# How to move an application window to another screen and switch to virtual-desk?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I have 2 screens. On the left screen(**A**) I have an app in fullscreen mode (as example: iTerm). If it try to move an application(as example: Chrome) from the right screen(**B**) to the left screen(**A**), it isn't possible, because I am blockt. I have first switch on the left screen(**A**) to the virtual-desktop window and only then I am able to move the application window via drag and drop from the right screen(**B**) to the left screen(**A**)

Is there a way to automatically switch to the virtual-desktop, when I move an app(as example: Chrome) from one screen(B) to screen(A)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this fully satisfies your request -
invoke Mission Control first (default key command  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>↑</kbd>  ), before dragging, then you can send your window anywhere…

[image]

Demo using just one display, to save space.

Comment: thank you. this make it a bit easier, on the other hand it have to think about it before I grab the window with my mouse. I though there is maybe an option to automatically switch to the virtual-desktop, but I understand that it could more difficult to implement because there can be multiple virtual-desktops on the screen.